# function using a pointer to a pointer with a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a function using a pointer to a pointer to a structure:

```
int function(struct_A ** mystructA);
```

It worked when i used it with my declared struct:

```
struct_A *mystructA;
function(&mystructA);
```

however, impossible to use my structure throught another structure:

```
struct struct_B{
    struct_A *mystructA;
}

struct_B mystructB;
function( (&mystructB)->mystructA );    //this line cause me a segfault
```

I am struggling here, any idea where it could come from?

Comment: `&(mystructB->mystructA)`

Comment: if you want to use it this strange way `function( &(&mystructB)->mystructA );`

Comment: Thanks it did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct struct_B{
    struct_A *mystructA;
}

struct struct_B mystructB;
struct struct_B *mystructBptr;

/* .... */

function( &mystructB.mystructA );
function( &(&mystructB) -> mystructA );
function( &mystructBptr -> mystructA );
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the following

```
struct struct_B{
    struct_A *mystructA;
}

struct struct_B mystructB;
function( &mystructB.mystructA );
```